# C++で異なる論理演算子を同時に使ったときの挙動が理解できない

Tags: c++

x = 2, y = 1, z = 0 のとき、

```
cout<< “answer =” <<(x||!y&&z)<< endl;
```

がどのように出力されるかについての質問です。

出力してみると、answer = 1となるのですが、なぜこのような結果となるかご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

演算子には下記サイトにあるような優先順位があります。
ここを手がかりに、式`(x||!y&&z)`の`||`と`!`と`&&`が評価される順番を整理してみてはいかがでしょうか。

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/126fe14k.aspx

Answer (score 2):

演算子の優先順位は

`!` > `&&` > `||`

です。なので

> !y
>
> > false
>
> !y && z
>
> > false
>
> x || !y && z
>
> > true

となります。つまり

> (x || ((!y) && z))

ですね。

なお GCCで`-Wall -Wextra`をつけてコンパイルすると

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:10:31: warning: suggest parentheses around '&&' within '||' [-Wparentheses]
     cout<< "answer =" <<(x||!y&&z)<< endl;
                             ~~^~~
```

のように怒られます。またClangで同様に`-Wall -Wextra`をつけてコンパイルすると

```
prog.cc:10:31: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
    cout<< "answer =" <<(x||!y&&z)<< endl;
                          ~~~~^~~
prog.cc:10:31: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
    cout<< "answer =" <<(x||!y&&z)<< endl;
                              ^
                            (    )
1 warning generated.
```

のように怒られます。実に親切なエラーメッセージですね！

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。この場合、x=2, y=1,z=0 といった数値を気にせずにtrue=1, false=0に着目すればよいとのことでしょうか？

Comment: 非0か0か、これが条件式のtrue/falseに該当します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。初心者のため、初歩的な質問をしてしまい失礼いたしました。

Comment: とりあえず教訓としては、コンパイルするときはgcc/clangなら-Wall -Wextraを、VSなら/W4をつけるようにしましょう、ということでしょうかね。

Comment: `A || B` で`A`がtrueの時`B`はそもそも評価されないことに注意して下さい。

Comment: あー、まあ確かに短絡評価されるから適切ではなかったですね。優先順位がわかりやすいかなと思って書いたstepでしたが